# use the epsilon delta definition to show $\lim_{x\to 0} \sqrt{x+1} = 1$

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

use the epsilon delta definition of limits to show that:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \sqrt{x+1} = 1$$

I am familiar with epsilon delta proofs, but i am not sure how to approch this problem.

Comment: Is it $\lim_{x\to 0} \sqrt{x+1} = 1$ ?

Comment: I'm totally confused as to what the problem is. For reference, in MathJax, braces `{ }` are used for grouping. If you want the square root of an expression, for example $\sqrt{x + 1}$, you type `\sqrt{x + 1}`.

Comment: yes, sorry. fixed it.

Comment: @JoakimHauger: I have edited the title to match the question. If this is not correct, please let me know.

Comment: yes, forgot that. thanks

Comment: @singerng Why? $\sqrt{x}$ is continuous at $x=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $\sqrt{x+1}-1=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x+1}+1}$